# Image border missing after downscaling

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, resize

When I resize a bitmap using Graphics class, it seams that some right and bottom pixels of the original image are omited.

Here is an example (original, 60x60, 30x30):

[image: original]
[image: result60]
[image: result30]

my code:

```
foreach(int x in new[]{60, 30})
{
    var result = new Bitmap(x, x);
    var g = Graphics.FromImage(result);
    g.DrawImage(new Bitmap(MediaDir + "original.png"), 0, 0, x, x);
    result.Save(MediaDir + "result" + x + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Am I missing something ?

edit, here is the result using HighQualityBicubic:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Set the interpolation mode to [`InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.interpolationmode.aspx).

You can see the effects of the parameter in a [Microsoft Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533836.aspx). The bottom left example has similar problems to yours.

Comment: Actually, i am already using InterpolationMode.Bicubic in my original code. It does not fix the issue.

Comment: @TomEsterez, I believe the difference between Bicubic and HighQualityBicubic is to directly address this problem.

Comment: HighQualityBicubic make the issue a bit less visible but still present.

Comment: @TomEsterez, interesting results, thanks. I would have expected better.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely to be an effect of the resizing process itself.  Depending on the algorithm used, it may be detecting the red colour of the pixels at the border as being no longer as relevant to the overall image as the white ones, so the white on is output.

Comment: I agree but it seams like a bug. Don't you think ?

Comment: That depends - If the specification for the algorithm says "only use the most significant colour for a pixel", then it is not a bug.  If it supposed to take an average colour density and output that, then yes, I'd agree.

Comment: This isn't a bug.  If you think about it, when you shrink an image you are going to lose data.  Smarter interpolation modes like HighQualityBicubic will lose less data, but they still lose data.  If you resize an image so every 3 pixels is merged in to one, that means 2 out of 3 will be discarded.  Your thin red line happens to be getting discarded.  If it were thicker (more than 1 pixel width) it would likely still appear.

Comment: @TomEsterez, it is not a bug. It's a tradeoff between speed and quality. The fastest algorithms don't take into account every single input pixel, and if they skip the pixel that contains the line then it won't show up in the output.

Comment: If you want to reliably show the red box, you can draw it with Graphics.DrawRectangle.  If you are using real-world images and not something abstract like a red box, then most likely the interpolation will be acceptable and won't seem erroneous.

Comment: I can andersand the performance compromize but even with HighQualityBicubic the result is not perfect.

Comment: @Moozhe, the red border image is just an example. But I ave visible problems with some "real life" images. So, is there any way to rescale images like any of my desktop apps do ?

Answer (score 0):

i used this workaround fot that "bug". When i resized standart eshop item photo, some have gray left/top border and some not. So u just use this code

```
g.DrawImage(src, -1, -1, width+1, height+1);
```

and its work perfectly. I also find some hints about pixelmode or try use some special attr with drawimage method but it doesnt work for me.